How do I link a Kotlin and Python project?
I have a python project with OCR, Image Processing steps. I want to do OCR operations by sending the photo I took with the Kotlin project to this Python file. How do I connect these two projects?
Can I use flask, django, cloud technologies etc. Which method would be easier?

Have you tried running your Python program as an external program? I don't know Kotlin specifics, but just about every language has a way to run an external program with command line arguments, and wait for it to finish.

I recommend using Flask, Its pretty easy to setup and straight forward.
Script for Flask:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import cv2
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/process_image', methods=['POST'])
def process_image():
    try:
        if 'input_image' not in request.files:
            return jsonify({'error': 'No file part'})
        
        file = request.files['input_image']
        imgarray = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(file.read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

        # Do anything you want with it

        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        # Return JSON output to kotlin file
        return jsonify({'output_image': 'Put the output image here'})
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Turn off debug in production
    app.run(debug=True)

